# Why vms on compute nodes can still boot so fast while big image file needs to be downloaded from storage nodes?

Tags: image, performance, virtual-machine, openstack

In OpenStack, vms can be booted in compute nodes. And the OS image files are stored in storage nodes which are usually different hosts from compute nodes. When user wants to boot a vm on a specific compute node, the image file(600M+) needs to be downloaded to compute node from storage nodes. This download may cost a lot of time, however, why does the vm still boot so fast(in 10~20 seconds)?

Answer (score 1):

nova-compute will usually try to cache any images it pulls from glance.  and reuse them on the next query.

also 600M+ at 1-10Gbit doesn't take very long to transfer 600MB.  In a 10Gbit linked openstack cluster that can be under a second. Assuming you have jumbo frames enabled and enough disk IO and the backhaul network is not saturated.  More likely it'll take 10 seconds or so =P.

Also many images are not 600megs.  Some are radically smaller.  The ttylinux images are only 96 or so megs.

ubuntu images are only a smidge over 200 megs generally:  http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/